# How to capture requests (in the form of curl) made from an app?

Tags: android, ios, curl

I have apps on Android and iOS and would like to capture requests made from those apps for load testing the API endpoint.

How can I achieve that?

I know there is Flipper but it seems like I need to setup the development environment. And there is man-in-the-middle-proxy but I can't copy curl from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flipper allows you to get cURL by right clicking on the API request made.

[cURL in Flipper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1M6b.png)